# Assembling a .asm file via FASM?

Tags: assembly, fasm

I downloaded a file for some experimentation and the instructions say

> "Download Flat Assembler
> or
> If you are on Linux, you may use `sudo apt-get install fasm`
> Assemble using the following command
> `fasm main.asm`"

I don't know how to do any of this as I'm new to all of this stuff. I don't even know if I should be running FASMW.EXE or FASM.EXE to do it. Neither way seems to do anything, so I'm just confused. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated! I've been working on it for the better part of 2 hours and I just cannot get it to work.

Comment: What do you mean by “Neither way seems to do anything?”  Are any output files being produced?  If successful, the `fasm` command does not print any output on the console.

Comment: Are you running it from a command-line window?  If you double-click on it, it would just run `fasm` with no arguments which prints help and then exits.  If your system is set to close the console window of a program that exited, this means the window closes again right away, so you don't even see the output.  I assume you're on Windows since you mention `.exe`?  Without a [mcve] of exactly what you tried and what happened, hard to guess.

Comment: No output is being produced. The error I get in the command line window is "D:\Downloads\fasmw17330>fasm main.asm
flat assembler  version 1.73.30  (1048576 kilobytes memory)
main.asm [91]:
    include '\fasm\include\win32ax.inc'
error: file not found."
@fuz

Comment: @PeterCordes I tried to assemble the code found [here](https://github.com/iDone/010-Editor-Keygen) and got the error `D:\Downloads\fasmw17330>fasm main.asm
flat assembler  version 1.73.30  (1048576 kilobytes memory)
main.asm [91]:
    include '\fasm\include\win32ax.inc'
error: file not found.`

Answer (score 2):

> I don't even know if I should be running FASMW.EXE or FASM.EXE to do it.

FASMW.EXE is the Integrated Development Environment for FASM. It's your easiest option to create programs with FASM.

- use <kbd>file</kbd><kbd>open</kbd> to load the source file eg. "keygen.asm"
- verify if <kbd>options</kbd><kbd>compiler setup</kbd><kbd>include path(s):</kbd> mentions the path to the header files eg. "C:\fasmw17324\INCLUDE"
- use <kbd>run</kbd><kbd>compile</kbd> to actually create the executable (no linker involved)

This works like a charm, although the source that you mention produces an executable of 7168 bytes instead of the 6260 bytes that were advertised!

---

If you're going to use the commandline version FASM.EXE, then make sure that the FASMW.INI file contains the path to the header files in its [Environment] section:

```
[Environment]
Include=C:\fasmw17324\INCLUDE
```